# Very simple pub/sub web app or script that interacts well with OSX/iOS?

Tags: ios, macos, webserver, publish-subscribe

I'm designing some OSX/iOS apps that I'd like to share a resource to be hosted on a webserver. I would like to have some sort of web app or script that can store a list of subscribers, and to notify them when the resource is updated. (The obvious goal here is to avoid having every app poll the webserver for updates.)

The only trick here is that I'd like a significant number of clients (say, a dozen) to be subscribed for updates on a 24/7 basis. I'm not sure if it's a good idea for all of the clients to maintain a live connection... I imagine that many web service providers will be happy about their webserver maintaining a dozen persistent connections (especially if they're virtually always idle).

**(Edit)** I looked into the Apple Push Network Service (APNs), but it's not the right solution for my problem. APNs requires an Entrust SSL Certificate, and some heavy interaction with the Apple Push Network service. My project is much simpler and more lightweight: I just need a script that says, "Upon receiving data from Device A, push it out to Devices B/C/D" (presuming those devices are somehow accessible... either through a persistent connection or some other technique).

What's the absolute simplest way of providing this mechanism?

Comment: Why not use the push notifications mechanism to tell the apps when there is something new?

Comment: I looked into that, but it's not really the right platform for my problem. I don't want my iOS apps to receive notifications while they're idle, but only while they're active and in the foreground. As best I can tell, iOS push notifications look like a decent solution for the former problem, but not the latter.

Comment: You could still use push notifications, just have the app subscribe on launch and unsubscribe on shutdown. You could use AWS Simple Notification Service (they have an iOS SDK although not OS X, that would need web service calls)

Comment: Having the app subscribe on launch / unsubscribe on shutdown doesn't seem like a great idea at all: it's not what APNS was designed to do. You risk running into issues with the feedback service on APNS.

Answer (score 0):

The "simplest way" probably means different things to different people. If you're not a fan of locking yourself into third party services then there's a veritable plethora of app frameworks and open source tools you could use to build something yourself. But this is hardly 'simple' if web app development isn't your strong point.

There are several 'off the shelf' services available to do real-time messaging on iOS: bear in mind I'm just listing the ones I know from memory, there are other alternatives. [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) and [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/) both offer real-time messaging services for mobile apps, along with ready to go SDKs. You can interface with them to send messages bi-directionally via sockets (so similar to how APNS works, but with considerable more control).

You could use these services with your own device/user management system, or you could use a 'backend as a service' provider such as Parse or Stackmob - you may not need this step, it depends how complex your intended app/integration is.

Answer (score 0):

XMPPFramework has a publish–subscribe module (for [XEP-0060](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html)) which works with most XMPP servers. I've even adapted it to work with Chat Server which comes with Snow Leopard.

If you already have an XMPP server this might be worth doing; otherwise it's kind of a heavyweight solution.